# How to call for "Label Detection" and "Safe Search Detection" at a time on Google Cloud Vision API

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I would like to ask you the the following thing about Vision API.

The following picture indicates that I can take on "Free with Label Detection, or $1.50", if I will use "Label Detection".
But, I didn't find out how to use both of them at the same time in a tutorial on "Label Detection" and "Safe Search Detection" both.

1. Can I use both of services at a time in Python?
2. If so, how can I call for them?

I will really appreciate that if you tell me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to send both types at the same time, you can use the `annotate_image()` method; in this way, you can specify all the **features** that need to be included in the same request. Based on this, I recommend you to take a look on this documentation ([Doc1](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/vision/gapic/v1/api.html#google.cloud.vision_v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.annotate_image), [Doc2](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/vision/index.html#annotate-an-image)) to get detailed information about this property usage, as well as this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/using-curl#creating_the_request_json), that contains a `curl` command example where is shown the process required to send multiple features within the same call that you can use as an alternative workaround.

```
import io
import os

from google.cloud import vision

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

response = client.annotate_image({
  'image': {'source': {'image_uri': '<IMAGE_URI>'}},
  'features': [{'type': vision.enums.Feature.Type.SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION},
               {'type': vision.enums.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION}]
})

print(response)
```

Additionally, I think that this pricing information refers that you can use the **Safe Search Detection** feature for free if you use it with **Label Detection**; however, the **Label Detection** requests will be billed with the corresponding charges that are displayed at the [Prices](https://cloud.google.com/vision/pricing#prices) document.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will try what you told me.

Comment: I made it! Thank you so much! You have saved me!