# Google Cloud Vision / PHP - Make single request with Label and Safe Search detection

Tags: php, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

On google cloud vision you get charged per request. If you do a "Label Detection" you get a free "Safe Search" but it has to be rolled into the same request. I have working code for both the Label Detection and the Safe Search detection but I am not sure how to combine the two into one request.

Someone had answered this question in Python but not sure how to translate it in PHP.

[How to call for "Label Detection" and "Safe Search Detection" at a time on Google Cloud Vision API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53195930/how-to-call-for-label-detection-and-safe-search-detection-at-a-time-on-googl)

Does anyone know how I could call them in PHP? Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
# imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient;

# instantiates a client
$imageAnnotator = new ImageAnnotatorClient();

# the name of the image file to annotate
$fileName = 'images/d4aed5533322946.jpg';

# prepare the image to be annotated
$image = file_get_contents($fileName);

# performs label detection on the image file
$response = $imageAnnotator->labelDetection($image);
$labels = $response->getLabelAnnotations();

if ($labels) {
    echo("Labels:" . PHP_EOL);
    foreach ($labels as $label) {
        echo($label->getDescription() . PHP_EOL);
    }
}
```

######### Safe Search would look as follows

```
function detect_safe_search($path)
{
    $imageAnnotator = new ImageAnnotatorClient();

    # annotate the image
    $image = file_get_contents($path);
    $response = $imageAnnotator->safeSearchDetection($image);
    $safe = $response->getSafeSearchAnnotation();

    $adult = $safe->getAdult();
    $medical = $safe->getMedical();
    $spoof = $safe->getSpoof();
    $violence = $safe->getViolence();
    $racy = $safe->getRacy();

    # names of likelihood from google.cloud.vision.enums
    $likelihoodName = ['UNKNOWN', 'VERY_UNLIKELY', 'UNLIKELY',
    'POSSIBLE','LIKELY', 'VERY_LIKELY'];

echo "Adult $adult\n";
    printf("Adult: %s" . PHP_EOL, $likelihoodName[$adult]);
    printf("Medical: %s" . PHP_EOL, $likelihoodName[$medical]);
    printf("Spoof: %s" . PHP_EOL, $likelihoodName[$spoof]);
    printf("Violence: %s" . PHP_EOL, $likelihoodName[$violence]);
    printf("Racy: %s" . PHP_EOL, $likelihoodName[$racy]);

    $imageAnnotator->close();
}

$path = 'images/d4aed5533322946.jpg';
detect_safe_search($path);

echo "\n";
$path = 'images/5.jpg.6f23b929dcc008f3bc394b0b6b0c6e5e.jpg';
detect_safe_search($path);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ImageAnnotatorClient::annotateImage`:

```
use Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\Feature\Type;
$res = $v->annotateImage(file_get_contents($fileName), [
    Type::LABEL_DETECTION,
    Type::SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION
]);

$labels = $res->getLabelAnnotations();
$safeSearch = $res->getSafeSearchAnnotation();
```